# Plotting a vector field embedded in a donut

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, mesh

I have the following code

```
meshFunc = Function[{u, v}, Sin[Pi (10 u - v)]];
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[2 Pi u], (2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[2 Pi u], Sin[2 Pi v]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, a, b}, meshFunc[a, b]], 
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick]]
```

which produces the plot

[image]

**Question:** How to add arrows to the mesh line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can post-process the output to change `Line`s into `Arrow`s and add the directive `Arrowheads`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[2 Pi u], (2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[2 Pi u], Sin[2 Pi v]},
  {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, a, b}, meshFunc[a, b]], 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick]] /. 
  Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[Table[.05, 10], Appearance -> "Projected"], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

You can also add the directive `Arrowheads` in the `MeshStyle` option setting and post-process to change `Line` to `Arrow`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[2 Pi u], (2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[2 Pi u], Sin[2 Pi v]},
  {u, 0,  1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, a, b}, meshFunc[a, b]], 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Arrowheads[Table[.05, 10], Appearance -> "Projected"]]] /. 
 Line -> Arrow
```

> same picture

Alternatively, specify the option value for `MeshStyle` as a function (this usage is undocumented):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Sin[2 Pi u], (2 + Cos[2 Pi v]) Cos[2 Pi u], Sin[2 Pi v]},
 {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z, a, b}, meshFunc[a, b]], 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> ({Thick, Arrowheads[Table[.05, 10], Appearance -> "Projected"], Arrow @@ #} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Just wonderful. Can you explain a little more the second method?

Comment: @Saavestro, when an option value can be specified as a function you can find out the default function using  `Print[{##}]&. In this case `MeshStyle -> (Print[{##}] &)` gives `{Line[...], Line[...]...}` , and `MeshStyle -> ({Thick, Arrowheads[Table[.05, 10], Appearance -> "Projected"], Arrow @@ #} &)` changes the head (`Line`) of each of these mesh elements to `Arrow`.